# Roundcube Address book configuration from slave database

Tags: roundcube

I am installing RC version..... on Debian .......

We are using PostgreSQL for authentication, ie all our email ids & passwords are in a Postgres table.
We query local roundcube database as

<$config['db_dsnw'] = 'pgsql://roundcube:Password@tcp(localhost:5434)/roundcubemail';>
It works, we are able to login & access email, send/receive, etc.

I have added Global Address Book as:
<$config['db_dsnw'] = 'pgsql://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost/dbname';>

and it is also working, email addresses get saved in it.

However, we are not able to get the email ids in our own domain when we start typing in the To: field.
How to link the ids of our own domain ( from the postgres email id auth table) to RC so that the when any email id is added there, it will appear when we start entering it in To field.

Comment: Roundcube version is "Version 1.4.11 " and  Debian version is debian 10 buster

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, there is a table named 'contacts' (may have prefix). You need to fill in keywords under the 'words' field. For example:

```
john smith john.smith@example.com example
```

Roundcube Global Address book will use these keywords to find the ids or email address.